# Eloquent Ruby: Building iterators that sequence through collections that don't actually exist

Tags: ruby

I'm reading "Eloquent Ruby" by Russ Olsen.  After the code below (Loc 3264) he states: "Notice that we never actually build a four-element array of all the word pairs: We simply generate the pairs on the fly."  I don't understand what's going on here.  What is words then?

```
class Document
    #Most of the class omitted...

    def each_word_pair  
        word_array = words
        index = 0
        while index < (word_array.size-1)
            yield word_array[index], word_array[index+1]
            index += 1
        end
    end
end

doc = Document.new('Donuts', '?', 'I love donuts mmmm donuts')
doc.each_word_pair{|first, second| puts "#{first} #{second}"}
#=> I love
#=> love donuts
#=> donuts mmmm
#=> mmmm donuts
```

Comment: It splits the sentence provided by whitespace and makes arrayy of them, words is the array

Comment: But the code doing this may be in one of previous examples :-)

Answer (score 6):

> What is words then?

`words` is the string `'I love donuts mmmm donuts'`, which is not the “four-element array of all the word pairs“ he’s speaking of.

> “Notice that we never actually build a four-element array of all the word pairs: We simply generate the pairs on the fly.” I don’t understand what's going on here.

He’s referring to the fact that the array `[["I", "love"], ["love", "donuts"], ["donuts", "mmmm"], ["mmmm", "donuts"]]` never exists within the `each_word_pair` method. This is because instead it creates each individual pair and then `yield`s them to the calling block. So it generates the first pair (`["I", "love"]`), `yield`s it, then does so for the next one. But `each_word_pair` itself never contains all four pairs together.

For example, we could have instead made this similar method:

```
def word_pairs
  word_array = words
  word_pairs = []

  index = 0
  while index < (word_array.size-1)
    word_pairs << [word_array[index], word_array[index+1]]
    index += 1
  end

  word_pairs
end
```

which creates an array with all four pairs and returns it. Note how we’ve had to construct an additional local variable (`word_pairs`) to hold the array we’re making, which wasn’t needed before because it just wasn’t stored at all.

<sub>*Note that `each_word_pair` is a somewhat-poorly written version of [Ruby core’s `each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) called with `2`.*</sub>

Comment: With your explanation I understand what he was trying to accomplish, but when I run the code it returns individual characters (not individual words). How would you get the full word?

Comment: @ltrainpr The code you provide is not complete as it doesn’t actually run, so I can’t fully test it. But it seems at some points `words` should be `split` on `' '`.

Comment: I think words should actually contain an array of words, e.g. `Words = 'an example sentence'.split`. That way, you will get the expected results.

Comment: The equivalent of this `each_word_pair` method it's not `each_slice(2)` but `each_cons(2)`.

Comment: @toro2k Whoops, that’s embarassing! Thanks for pointing out my late-night error `:)`.

Comment: @paddle It makes sense to me that the words should be split, but that would produce the 4 element array that Russ Olsen states is avoided.  What am i missing?  Here you go [link](http://books.google.com/books?id=-s2xL0pVsLUC&pg=PA213&lpg=PA213&dq=eloquent+ruby+Notice+that+we+never+actually+build+a+four-element+array+of+all+the+word+pairs:+We+simply+generate+the+pairs+on+the+fly.&source=bl&ots=l7M0fzN8O7&sig=ablZYLZYPOSlQLbJj0TfX0e9Yls&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KZT1UeqLFobcyQGS7oDYDg&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAg)

Comment: @ltrainpr No, because he’s talking about a four-element array of array *pairs*, not of strings.

Comment: Ohh I get it now. Thank you for re-clarifying this for me. Dumb moment, my apologies.